# Do Red Slaad Eggs in Spellcasters Create Green Slaadi?

Tags: dnd-5e

The PCs encountered a red slaad. If the slaad clawed a target, and the target failed the saving throw, if the target could cast spells of 3rd level or higher, would the egg turn into a green slaad?

Comment: I posted an answer, though it isn’t entirely clear what is confusing about the red slaad description. If I’m missing something about your question, please let us know.

Comment: I haven't read the Monster Manual in a while.

Comment: The downvotes you are seeing is because you know this is in the MM, but came here instead of reading it for yourself. That is a lack of research effort which doesn't go down well here. We work best after you read the rules and don't understand something specific, or find them unclear, rather than just haven't read the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red slaad description states:

> **When a red slaad claws a humanoid creature**, it can inject an egg from a gland under one of its claws. The egg works its way into its host and gestates, eventually forming a slaad tadpole. Such a tadpole then eats its way out of the host’s body, feeds on the host’s remains, and then seeks any other fresh meat it can find. The tadpole transforms into a fully grown blue slaad — **or green slaad if the host had the ability to cast 3rd level spells or higher** — within 2d12 hours.

Comment: The red slaad egg creates Stalin salad, while a green slaad egg creates Caesar's salad. 